# Grunt neuter duplicate content

Tags: gruntjs, vagrant

For the last few days I'm facing problem with Grunt-neuter, it duplicates content of files.

My source folders structure:

```
javascript/
    main.js (with @import()'s )
    routes/
        route_home.js
        route_about.js
        route_contact.js
        route_products.js
```

My destination folder structure should look like source and I get it right.
What is wrong that after neuter route files have same content (route_home.js == route_about.js etc.)

Neuter task:

```
        neuter: {
        main: {
            options: {
                filepathTransform: function (filepath) {
                    return config.app + '/' + filepath;
                }
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/public/js',
                src: ['*.js'],
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts'
            }]
        },
        routs: {
            options: {
                filepathTransform: function (filepath) {
                    return config.app + '/' + filepath;
                }
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/public/js/routs/',
                src: ['**/*.js'],
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/routs'
            }]
        }
    },
```

I splited this task to two, because before that main.js content was same as routes files.

(Ubuntu 14.04 running on Vagrant)

**Updated:**

Still can't get right way to do that.

So, I'll give you some examples, maybe anyone could help me.

This is two route files content route_about.js:

```
//route_about.js
```

route_houme.js:

```
//route_home.js
```

And this is output route_about.js:

```
(function() {

//route_about.js

})();
```

route_houme.js:

```
(function() {

(function() {

//route_about.js

})();

})();

(function() {

//route_home.js

})();
```

As you can see, first file is OK, but second takes first's content surround with function() and then add second file content.

Or maybe you could offer any atlernatives to do this task?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I find out that there is problem with Grunt-neuter plugin. Made some changes for it and now it works as it should.

If you would look into neuter task, you would see that there is two variables 'requested' and 'out' witch contains parameters for every file. The problem is these variables contains old values from last files iteration. To fix this you need to add these lines:

```
            });

    **required = []; //at 144 line**

  // test if template block has newlines to offset against
  var m, n, beforeOffset, afterOffset;

{...}

        grunt.file.write(file.dest + ".map", JSON.stringify(newSourceMap, null, '  '));
        }
    **out = []; //at line 200**
});
```